# Synonymize [lesson-planning] into [lesson-ideas]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[lesson-planning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-planning) has only three questions, and the much wider used [lesson-ideas](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-ideas) is for questions about

> planning lessons for a specific purpose, such as teaching some coding paradigm or skill. Planning lessons in Computer Science depends on the context and level of the students. If it is a lesson which introduces a new topic, the tag [introductory-lesson] may also be appropriate.

Given that, would it make sense to make [lesson-planning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-planning) a synonym of [lesson-ideas](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-ideas)?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I just changed the tags on the three questions so now lesson-planning has none. It had no tag wiki in any case.

Note that whenever I find a brand new tag that has no wiki, I try to see if we already have one (or two) that covers the case and is already used. In that situation I consider replacing the new tag with older, established, ones. The proliferation of tags can actually make it harder to find related things.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could have done that (though I have already a couple of pending suggested edits), but it might be that somebody creates the tag again in the future (not sure how likely that is). A synonym would permanently point to the new tag.

Comment: Yeah, I probably would have preferred a synonym, but under the circumstances, I'll just wait to see if it actually appears again.

Comment: @BenI., too many tags gets in the way, I think. In particular it becomes harder to find an appropriate tag and makes users want to add new ones, making the problem worse. Especially when they don't add wiki explaining the intent. I think mod action is required to merge existing tags.

Comment: @Buffy Agreed.  Tag synonyms are a mod tool to get rid of a tag permanently, and automatically redirect to the desired tag if someone starts typing the removed one.  They are a more permanent way to remove tags.

Comment: @NOTCSEducator, please stop doing this. You don't have the authority to do it. These comments are noise and the chat room is not part of this site anyway.